# Best way to do syntax highlighting in GTK+?

Tags: c, syntax-highlighting, gtk

I was wondering if someone could point me to an example of (or just their thoughts on) the best way to code syntax highlighting in a C-based GTK+ application. I know that I can use the GtkTextTag to modify text in a GtkTextBuffer but beyond searching out keywords (iteratively or by regexing the string) is there a better way? My only concern is that if I wipe all of the tags and then re-search and apply the tags at every text change event it could really bog down my application.

As always thanks for your help!

Comment: Why can't you use a GtkSourceview?

Comment: Well I guess I figured I should keep it consistent seeing as GLADE is targeting GTK+ 2.16 which to my knowledge doesn't support GtkSourceview. You raise a good point though. Is there a good tutorial somewhere to help me figure out how to use GtkSourceview?

Comment: Glade doesn't include widgets for GtkSourceView, but the GtkSourceView source code includes a Glade widget catalog that enables GtkSourceView for Glade. If your distribution doesn't install it along with the GtkSourceView development package, download it here: http://git.gnome.org/browse/gtksourceview/tree/data/glade/gtksourceview.xml.in then rename it to gtksourceview.xml. To find out what directory to copy it to, run this: `pkg-config --variable=catalogdir gladeui-1.0`.

Comment: Also, file a bug with your distribution, telling them to add `--enable-glade-catalog` to the configure flags for the GtkSourceView development package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got GtkSourceview to work and it works well.